# I want to display records of current date in order of pending, solved, cancel

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have records like this:

```
empid     title     complaint_description  complain_date     status
 1         jjn          kkjjj              3/march/14       Solved

 2        jjkjn         jnkjnj             18/mar/14        pending

 3        kjjk          jkhjk              21/mar/14         Cancel

 4        jkjh          jhkj               22/mar/14         Solved

 5        jkjj          jkhjk              22/mar/14         pending

 6        nkjn          nkjnk              22/marc/14        pending

 7        nkjn          jnk                22/marc/14         cancel
```

I want the Linq query to display all complaints of current date in order like Pending, Solved, Cancel:

```
jkjh        jhkj         22/mar/14     pending

jkjj        jkhjk        22/mar/14     pending

nkjn        nkjnk        22/marc/14    Solved

nkjn        jnk      22/marc/14    cancel.
```

Can anyone provide me a Linq query for my above problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can search object from list and add by station pending ,solved and cancel;;

```
var query = lstEmployee.FindAll(a=>a.complain_date=DateTime.Today & a.status="pending");

query.AddRange= lstEmployee.FindAll(a=>a.complain_date=DateTime.Today & a.status="Solved");

query.AddRange= lstEmployee.FindAll(a=>a.complain_date=DateTime.Today & a.status="cancel");
```

Comment: but then i would i return final result??? because this final result i want to display in my gridview.please can u provide me full solution??

Comment: in `query` object have all final resuly .. you need to just give `gridview.datesource=query`

Comment: once again thank u so much brother.thank u so much.i am very new to linq so i dont know much in linq.

Comment: great..you can find more info here on stack we are ready to help newbi e :)

Comment: bro you there on facebook??

Comment: i have send you request on facebook.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/asp-net here is a chat blog if u have any qustion ..

Comment: bro i dont have much reputation to talk there

Comment: can u please show me by code how to take records in lstEmployee??